# Having trouble getting UIImagePickerController Working

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two classes: View1 and SelectImage. View1 imports SelectImage. SelectImage is used to present a UIView to the user which allows them to select how to grab a photo from their device. Tapping a button in that list then sends a message to one of the methods below...

In this code:

```
-(void)importFromCamera:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}

-(void)importFromPhotoLibrary:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}

-(void)importFromSavedPhotosAlbum:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
    UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController alloc];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

the compiler complains:

> Receiver type 'SelectImage' for instance message does not declare a
>   method with selector 'presentModalViewController:animated:'

At each instance of [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

Not sure what I'm missing. I've looked around and can only find examples that keep everything in one class.

Is it because the class is a UIView and not a UIViewController? I'm pretty sure I have the necessary delegate protocols in place: .

I'm trying to keep this functionality contained in a class to allow other views to use it as well (View2, View3, etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. presentModalViewController is a method on `UIViewController` not `UIView`

Note that on iOS 5 the preferred method to use is:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

`SelectImage` class could have a delegate which your `UIViewController` implements. The action methods of your buttons on SelectImage class would call your delegate (ie. the UIViewController).

Answer (score 0):

SelectImage should be a UIViewController.  Call it SelectImageController, then view1 can add it's view like `[view1 addSubview:self.selectImageController.view];`